# Write a specific bit in a 16bits register with modbus in python

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I try to communicate with a m221 module (schneider Electrique) who use modbus protocol.
I can read and write value of a register with pymodbus (read_input_register, write_register) but for control the m221 module, I need to set only one bit of register to 1. (Ex : bit 11 of register 10).

anyone know how i can do that or just if it's even possible?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what exactly you need help with. Are you looking for ``1 << 11``, i.e. setting the 11'th bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the 16bit register, modify the bit and write it back. This of course is not an atomic operation so if something else modifies one of the other bits in the middle of your read-modify-write cycle, then you are overwriting their changes.

Some devices support function 0x16 which is a Mask Write to a register, i.e. AND + OR bitmasks are supplied to indicate which bits in the register are actually being written and then other bits will be left unmodified.

Edit: actually pymodbus seems to support Mask Write Register.

To set bit 11 of register 10:

```
client.mask_write_register(10, and_mask=0xFFFF, or_mask=0b0000000000100000)
```

This is assuming bit 11 means the 11th bit counting from MSB towards LSB.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i dont really know how masks work here. all bits have been set to 0 except bit 11 to 1 or only bit 11 has been written?

Comment: Only bit 11 is changed. The AND mask is used to clear bits by setting them to 0 in the mask. The OR mask is used to set bits by setting them to 1 in the mask. An `and_mask` of 0xFFFF means don't clear any of the 16 bits. If you AND something with 0xFFF0 for example, you would clear the last 8 bits. Then the OR mask is applied and we only set bit 11 in it, forcing it to be turned on in the register.